# Linq relational table include

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I have 4 relational table;

1. Category
2. Product
3. ProductBrand
4. ProductImage

I need `linq` query included *3 tables* group by `ProductBrand from CategoryId`.

I try this;

```
var PBrand = from b in db.ProductBrands
                       join p in db.Products on b.BrandId equals p.BrandId
                       join i in db.ProductImages on p.ProductId equals i.ProductId 
                       where b.CategoryId == 5
                       select b;
```

but `Products` and `ProductImages` are null. How I include `Products` and `ProductImages` table on `Brand` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
from b in db.ProductBrands.Include("Products.ProductImages") 
where b.CategoryId == 5
select b;
```

Or the [extension method `Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, it's work. I tried before it; from b in db.ProductBrands.Include(x => x.Products) .. but I don't include Images :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just **select b**, write like this 
select b.col1, i.col1, b.coln, i.coln....;

The above will always return anonymous type object instead of a specific class...

Thanks